# How improve data-transfer speed of my android application

Tags: android

Please any one can explain me how to improve speed beetween mobile and server in my android application.
now am using traditional method like http.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to be in control of the server if it is third party servers you are out of luck.  For Simultaneous request in succession you can use websockets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket.  The benefit is not have the http request overhead on each request.  Also you could HTTP ETag http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag for situations where the response may be the same.

Comment: Do you have any samples...if you have can you share with me...thanks

Comment: @user3675552 in which language do you want samples?  Also could you add more context to the situation where the data transfer is slow.

Comment: here am using android,java,php....while loading json data from server to application it is taking time is it possible to reduce....

Comment: @user3675552 So it is one JSON Payload (HTTP Request).  How big is the Payload?  Is your UI dependant on that data or can it be run in a service in the background